# How can I stop Grape from JSON-encoding my output twice?

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-grape, rails-roar

I'm currently implementing a JSON based Grape API. I've integrated roar for JSON serailization and deserialization. When executing the following code, it seems that the JSON is encoded twice resulting a response with slashes. Is there anyway on Grape to suppress the JSON decode when required?

`json = UserRepresenter.new(user).to_json
{ status: StatusResponse::VALID, message: json }`

Answer (score 0):

Grape automatically encodes the output as JSON (when `format :json` is specified) so the `to_json` call in your code is superfluous.

Try changing your code to simply this:

```
{ status: StatusResponse::VALID, message: UserRepresenter.new(user) }
```